# Trying to generate a pfx from crt and private key from GoDaddy using openssl fails with No certificate matches private key

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm trying to generate a pfx file from a crt and a private key, and I keep getting `No certificate matches private key`.

No idea what's going on here.
I did:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out myaudiservice.com.pfx -inkey myaudiservice.com.key -in myaudiservice.com.crt -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

Which gets me:

```
No certificate matches private key
```

So, I tried deleting everything, key, crt, cert chain, and then I generated a new CSR:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout myaudiservice.com.key -out myaudiservice.com.csr
```

Which generated a new key and new csr.  I then uploaded the CSR to GoDaddy and requested the cert be re-keyed.

When that was done, I downloaded the new crt, and used the freshly generated key (from the openssl command used to generate the CSR), and I still get the same error.

Then, just as a sanity check I did:

```
mjb@bohr:~/Downloads/myaudiservice.com$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in myaudiservice.com.crt | openssl md5
(stdin)= 36d37e4f8f8672c127178a4a9cf32b89
mjb@bohr:~/Downloads/myaudiservice.com$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in myaudiservice.com.key | openssl md5
(stdin)= 36d37e4f8f8672c127178a4a9cf32b89
```

And they match....but I still get the:

```
No certificate matches private key
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple `-in` arguments. It will just take the last, i.e. `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. And no certificate in this file matches the key. Instead you should combine all certificates (and maybe even the key) into a single file and use this as argument for a single `-in` option.

Comment: Wow....absolutely correct!  I could have *sworn* I did it with multiple -in arguements in the past with no problem...but doing as you said, immediately fixed the problem!  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW instead of putting them in `-in`/stdin, you can provide the chain certs (as _one_ file, which gd_bundle is) with `-certfile`, or have them in the local truststore (`-CAfile` and/or `-CApath` and/or their defaults) _and_ specify `-chain`. A plethora of choices.